# Is "rendered output" for an edit supposed to show markup?

Tags: support

I try to approve some edits. Often if the edit really improves the text depends on how the new markup will be rendered. Selecting "rendered output" I just see the markup, not the rendered output. Why? Bug? Problem with my browser (Firefox)?

Comment: The issue seems to be that the newly added parts are highlighted in green, and some MathJax within the highlighted sections is not rendered. [I tried it on my computer by suggesting an edit for one of my own posts from incognito mode.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tl7ey.png) I suspect that whatever is used for the begin/end green highlighting interferes with the MathJax; so, when an entire new equation has been added, it will be rendered perfectly OK. However, when an existing equation is edited, that leads to the different behaviour.

Comment: Note that: 1) the first section of green highlighting ends before the closing `...$$`, and the MathJax does not render. 2) The entirely new additions `\cp`, `\cv` , and `\endgroup ... \ln \mathrm{e} = 1` are rendered in MathJax. 3) However, since the first section was not rendered, the newly defined commands `\cp` and `\cv`, as well as `\endgroup` (which requires the `begingroup` package), throw a MathJax error. (The red-coloured text, as well as the "testing 1/2 ln e = 1", indicate that MathJax has been rendered.)

Comment: This should probably go to the main meta as it affects all sites.

Answer (score 5):

I have noticed that some parts of some MathJax are rendered while other parts of MathJax are not. Thus, I usually stick to the *markdown* view (i.e. code) on Chemistry.SE, give or take the odd exception.

I suspekt that this is due to the following workflow of the edit highlighting code:

- It detects different words in both versions, highlights the old one red with strikethrough, the new ones green with highlight. This is done by putting the *entire* word into an appropriate box (`<div>`?)
- Once that has happened, the MathJax renderer gets to see the page. It will only detect those sets of `$` signs that have been placed *validly* — no MathJax across paragraphs and probably not across HTML unit boundaries either.

Therefore, if changes have been made *within the code* and the code is *not a single word,* the changes will cause the MathJax to be broken apart there — especially if the `$` sign is affected and the `$` signs outside now suddenly do not match.

This is confirmed by [ortho’s suggested testing edit](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/50315):

- The first modifies the ‘word’ `$$C_p` to the new ‘word’ `$$\require{begingroup}` with a lot of additional words following. Or maybe the ‘new word’ is considered to be `$$\require{begingroup} \begingroup \newcommand{\cp}[0]{C_p}`. It doesn’t really matter at this point. Since the edit breaks the sequence of `$` signs which no longer match, it is incorrectly displayed.
- The second and third bits of MathJax modify an entire word completely. Thus, the rendered output has a correct set of matching `$` signs within each group — the MathJax renders.

  - The command `\cp` has been defined in a portion of the MathJax that did not render. Therefore, it is not defined as far as MathJax is concerned.
- The final code is completely new, thus enclosed as a set of ‘new words’ in its own green highlighting code and thus renders as expected (see sub bullet point above).

Further testing may be required to see:

- what happens if changes are performed *fully within the code:*

  `$503 - 102 = 402$` → `$503 - 101 = 402$`

  This could be interpreted or could not be; I don’t know which path is taken. The issue is that the ‘word’ that would cause the highlighting is completely confined within the MathJax that *could* render (or maybe also could not).

Of course, my assumptions could be complete crap, too.